# Chrome Packaged App Share Screen Popup Clipped On Windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have been working on a chrome packaged app, which requires desktopCapture permission from the user. The window size of the app is fixed. The issue is when the user opens the app he is asked to grant permission for sharing his screen. The popup appears just fine on other OS's other than Windows. In case of Windows the popup is clipped in half (please see the attached image).

Can any one help please.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMPDm.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind filing a bug at http://crbug.com/new so that the chromium team cam have a look? It is definitely a bug.